# target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.tool', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform

Tags: iphone

Please Resolved this type Error for generating to debugging i-phone application.

Thanks 
Anil

Comment: If you're building WebKit and ran into this error, you forgot to run the embedded development script (see the WebKit README)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to build a command line tool for the iPhone, which isn't supported. The error speaks the truth.

You can't build command line apps for the iPhone.

Comment: Hey friend thanks but why are you not using command line tool for i-phone application

Comment: Because it is not possible. It is not allowed by Apple.

Comment: To be clear, go in `Build Settings` and change the `Supported Platforms` setting from its current value (probably all platforms) to `macOS` only.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of at least one legitimate scenario for this - building a command-line unit test project.

In my case I'm have a large amount of C++ in my project and am happy unit testing it natively on the Mac rather than on the target.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in Ecode to resolve it simply i have changed

```
com.apple.product-type.tool to com.apple.product-type.application
```

To resolve this issue go through 
`AppName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` and make changes according to above code.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is one of the comments in the answers..  `Build Settings` then change `Supported Platforms` to `macOS`

Answer (score 0):

Not only change the `Supported Platforms` to macOS, but also the `baseSDK` as well.

[image]